# My notifications Bar

Tags: htc-one-m8

Don't mind the wallpaper, that's for me because I'm proving in these area and it will help break my procrastination.
The real issue is my notification bar.

[image: Not On Home Screen]

[image: On Home Screen]

Can anyone help me? I tried Googling it, but I don't know how to describe my problem.